# SQL SELECT 3 Tables With 2 Different IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a MySQL query which merges data from three tables. Unfortunately, the IDs used to organize the data are different for two of the tables, but are related on the third table. The first table is setup this way:

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | ID | Meta_Key  | Meta_Value           |
 +---------------------------------------+
 | 1  | name      | John Doe             |                      
 +---------------------------------------+
```

The 2nd Table is setup this way:

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | ID  | Order_Type      |  Order_ID     |
 +---------------------------------------+
 | 1   | order_type1     |  101          |
 +---------------------------------------+
```

And the 3rd table is setup this way:

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | Order_ID  | Order_Key  | Order_Value  |
 +---------------------------------------+
 | 101       | order_total| 1000         |
 +---------------------------------------+
```

I'm looking for a way to merge these three tables using a SELECT query, and group them by the ID like so:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------------+
 | ID  | Order_ID  | Meta_Value  | Order_Type  | Order_Value |
 +-----------------------------------------------------------+
 | 1   | 101       | John Doe    | order_type1 | 1000        |
 +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Seems like you want a `JOIN`! (A double one.)

Comment: I'm such a SQL noob, is it possible to join 3 tables and organize the data based on the two IDs, though?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to relate them. I thought maybe the fact that the 2nd table contains IDs for both the 1st and 3rd tables might make it possible.

Comment: @gffwebdev, yes, you can join as many tables as you want with any logic you want, you just need to validate your output that you're getting the true positives of your logical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all three tables and select the fields you need.

```
SELECT 
 FirstTable.ID, 
 SecondTable.Order_ID, 
 FirstTable.Meta_Value, 
 SecondTable.Order_Type, 
 ThirdTable.Order_Value
FROM FirstTable 
JOIN SecondTable ON FirstTable.ID = SecondTable.ID 
JOIN ThirdTable ON SecondTable.Order_ID = ThirdTable.Order_ID
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a joins will do:

```
select t1.id,
    t2.order_id,
    t1.meta_value,
    t2.order_type,
    t3.order_value
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join table3 t2 on t2.order_id = t3.order_id
where t1.meta_key = 'name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple tables on multiple criteria:

```
select
[desired fields]
from tbl_1
     inner join tbl_2 on tbl_1.ID = tbl_2.ID
     inner join tbl_3 on tbl_2.Order_ID = tbl_3.Order_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.ID, T2.Order_ID, T1.Meta_Value, T2.Order_Type, T3.Order_Value 
FROM Table_1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT  JOIN Table_3 T3 ON T2.Order_ID= T3.Order_ID
```

Please use above query to make view

Comment: I'm curious why you utilize a view?